# Power Shell failed. Installing Microsoft SQL server 2008 r2 on Windows XP

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008, powershell

I am trying to install sql server 2008 r2 on windows Xp, but the installation fails because of `Power Shell failed`. I tried searching a bit and got to know before moving ahead u need power shell to be installed. 
I downloaded it from microsoft as `Windows6.0-KB2506146-x86.msu` now the msu file does not run with double click, I used cmd prompt and extracted it on temp as per the doc on microsoft then I tried using `pkgmgr.exe` to install but cmd does not recognize it. Then I used `WUSA.exe` which  is also not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot install `.msu` update packages on Windows XP, because that package format pertains to Windows Vista and newer. Also, PowerShell v3 isn't available for Windows XP in the first place. You can install [PowerShell v2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929), though.